# build shopping cart in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have json file

```
 {
   "cpu":[
         {"code":"CPUB028","name":"Block CPU EK Supre","price":"1.789.000"},
          {"code":"CPUIT5","name":"CPU INTEL CORE I5","price":"8.789.000" }
            ], 
    "vga":[
          {"code":"VGAASTI","name":" VGA GTX Gigabyte 1080Ti","price":"20.999.000"},
            {"code":"VGARX47","name":"VGA RADEON RX470","price":"8.900.000"}
    ]}
```

i use angular display this in page shop

```
<tr ng-repeat="cpu in vm.mydata.cpu">
         <td>{{cpu.name}}</td>
         <td>{{cpu.price}}</td>
<button>Buy</button>
</tr>
 <tr ng-repeat="cpu in vm.mydata.cpu">
         <td>{{cpu.name}}</td>
         <td>{{cpu.price}}</td>
<button>Buy</button> 
</tr>
```

I want when click button buy , iteam display in another page , and count money . What can i do ? Pls help me

Comment: use ngClick to fire an angular event, and by using model binding you will get the data.

Comment: Could you please refer to the specific example . Pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of ways to implement this. Like

- Storing the preferences in backend using API.
- Store cart details in session storage or local storage and can reuse these in any pages.
- Using angular values for passing values thorughout different pages.

For easier implementations, you could use [ng-cart](https://github.com/snapjay/ngCart) which is a simple client side cart implementation and is easy to add to the project.

Comment: Could you please refer to the specific example . Pls

Comment: Please refer the docs. Its pretty much easy to implement. http://ngcart.snapjay.com/docs. And do upvote if it helped

Comment: But how can I add id when i use ng-repeat